# Switching from a tooltip on desktop to a pop-up on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

Reflecting back on an old question, I was thinking about adding onto this specific answer [in which the tooltip moves with the user's mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270635/15148624). At a screen size of 1075px and greater, I'd like the tooltip to behave as it does in my code below, but at a screen size of 1074px or less, I'd like the same tooltip to pop-up instead when the user taps on 'Check Here'. I need the pop-up to be centered to the window.

```js
const objects = document.querySelectorAll("[data-tooltip]");

objects.forEach(object =>
  object.addEventListener("mousemove", ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    const tooltipId = object.getAttribute("data-tooltip");
    
    const tooltip = document.getElementById(tooltipId);

    tooltip.style.display = "block";

    tooltip.style.left = `${clientX}px`;
    tooltip.style.top = `${clientY}px`;
  })
);

objects.forEach(object =>
  object.addEventListener("mouseout", ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    const tooltipId = object.getAttribute("data-tooltip");

    const tooltip = document.getElementById(tooltipId);

    tooltip.style.display = "none";
  })
);
```

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  }

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }

img{
  width: 40px;
  }

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
```

```html
<p>Not sure of what product you have?</p> 

    <span data-tooltip="tooltip_products">Check here.</span>
            
    <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip_products">
      <table>
        <tr>
           <td><img src="site/circle.png" alt="Red circle"></td>
           <td>Circle</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><img src="site/square.png" alt="Blue square"></td>
           <td>Square</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><img src="site/hexagon.png" alt="Yellow hexagon"></td>
         <td>Hexagon</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two uses of the @media only screen max width should do the trick with one class only existing on mobile and another only existing on the other viewport

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1075px) {
 tooltip {
whatever styling you have
}
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1074px) {
mobileTooltip {
whatever styling you have
}
}
```

You would have to add the new div mobileTooltip to your html after.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that media queries could be used if I created two different tooltips with two separate scripts. I now realize that I didn't make this clear in my original question: I'm wondering if it is possible to instead change from the tooltip to a pop-up within one script using an if/else statement rather than creating two separate tooltips? I'm still learning Javascript so I haven't done anything this complex.

Comment: You would want to get the element by using const tooltip=document.getElementById(id); and then you can switch the class with tooltip.className with an if else statement. You would have two tooltips in the css but only one div in the html.